# define variable by concatenating strings

Tags: matlab, eval, string-concatenation

I want to iteratively define a variable whose name is the concatenation of two strings.

In particular, the following code is meant to create a variable **Uvel_spring** that contains the values **Uvel** stored in the file **spring_surface.mat** :

```
seasons{1}='spring';
seasons{2}='summer';
seasons{3}='autumn';
seasons{4}='winter';

for ii=1:4

    ['Uvel_',char(seasons(ii))] = load([char(seasons(ii)),'_surface.mat'],...
             'Uvel');

end
```

However, I get the following error:

> An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING.

I solved it by using `evalc`:

```
for ii=1:4

   evalc( sprintf(['Uvel_',char(seasons(ii)),'=','load(''',char(seasons(ii)),'_surface.mat'',',...
             '''Uvel''',')']) );

end
```

However, it is horrible and I would like to improve the code.

Does someone have an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`struct`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) instead.

```
for ii=1:4
    Uvel.(seasons{ii}) = load([seasons{ii},'_surface.mat'], 'Uvel');
end
```

You'll end up having those four seasons as the fields of `Uvel`. So you'll be accessing `Uvel_spring` as `Uvel.spring` and similarly for others.